# What is the diff between initializing a global struct pointer vs a global struct in golang?

Tags: go

Let's say I have the following code

```
//var mystruct *MyStruct  // method 1
//var mystruct MyStruct   // method 2

type MyStruct struct {
   // struct fields
}
```

I understand the basic differences between method 1 and method 2 in terms of declaring the mystruct variable. Both of them requires allocating the same amount of memory and the first method requires an additional pointer. The first method allocates memory on heap and the second method allocates on stack. I imagine the first method is preferred if stack memory can be under pressure.

Does it have any other practical differences between these two ways of declaring a struct variable as a global variable within the package?

Comment: Your reasoning is completely flawed. Go, the language has no concept of heap and stack. Some implementations distinguish between heap and stack and place objects where they see them fit and you cannot really control this decision. For newcomers unaccustomed to pointers the "pointer stuff" seems to be complicated, so focus on the relevant things and not on irrelevant, uncontrollable, low-level implementation details.

Comment: Forget about heap/stack in Go until a) you understand pointer stuff _and_ b) you profiled your code and proved that heap allocation is _the_ bottlenck on the hot code path.

Comment: @Volker thanks for the feedbacks. So your recommendation is 1 or 2 above before profiling and identifying the bottleneck?

Comment: 1 or 2 are different and serve different purposes, nobody can recommend one over the other. It's like asking "beer or steak, which do you recommend?". Are you thirsty or hungry?

Comment: If you want to elaborate the thirsty and hungry definition, that would help and what I am looking for as the question is asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declaring a pointer does not allocate memory on the heap. It just declares a pointer.

If you declare an instance of a struct (not a pointer), then the memory for that struct is allocated on the heap, and stays there. The symbol name used to declare it (`myStruct`) always refers to that struct instance.

If you declare a pointer `*myStruct` as above, it is initialized to nil. Accessing it will panic. You have to assign `myStruct` to the address of an allocated instance of `MyStruct`. One important difference is that if you declare a pointer, where it points may change during the program.

Comment: Yes, you are right. For the pointer i would need to allocate a struct for it to points to. But it seems that the performance impact will not be a concern (not during allocation, during referencing the variable)?

Comment: Seems what you are indicating is there is no real practical differences that impacts program performance or other non functional aspects besides slight diff between the memory allocations?

Comment: Accessing through a pointer is slower because of the indirection. Usually that is so small that it can be safely ignored. However, if there is no reason for it to be a pointer, then it should not be a pointer.